# Using OpenStack Nova Exceptions

Tags: python, exception, openstack, openstack-nova

When I'm using `nova.keypairs.create()` and I pass it an invalid public key, I get the following:

```
BadRequest: Keypair data is invalid: failed to generate fingerprint (HTTP 400) (Request-ID: req-12bc6440-f042-4687-9ee9-d89e7edc260d)
```

I tried doing the following and for obvious reasons (it's a unique exception to OpenStack) it didn't work:

```
try:
    nova.keypairs.create(name=keyname, public_key=key)
except BadRequest:
    raise cherrypy.HTTPError(400, "Invalid public key")
```

How can I use OpenStack specific exceptions such as `BadRequest` within my own try and except statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to import the exceptions for nova package. Going through [github for the package](https://github.com/openstack/nova/blob/4f91ed3a547965ed96a22520edcfb783e7936e95/nova/exception.py), it looks like you will need to do:

```
from nova.exception import *
```

Note that the exception you are seeing is actually [`InvalidKeypair`](https://github.com/openstack/nova/blob/4f91ed3a547965ed96a22520edcfb783e7936e95/nova/exception.py#L273) exception, which itself subclasses from exception class [`Invalid`](https://github.com/openstack/nova/blob/4f91ed3a547965ed96a22520edcfb783e7936e95/nova/exception.py#L178), the `BadRequest` message is just the template text for it.

So, your complete code would look something like:

```
from nova.exception import *
# You can import specific ones if you are confident about them
try:
    nova.keypairs.create(name=keyname, public_key=key)
except InvalidKeypair:
    raise cherrypy.HTTPError(400, "Invalid public key")
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's because I'm using Nova version 2.1, but I had to change the except from `InvalidKeypair` to `BadRequest` (I had a `NameError` stating that `InvalidKeypair` isn't defined. Seems a bit silly that it'll now get every bad request as opposed to only raising an error when there's an invalid keypair but it could just be I'm using an old version.

Comment: @MRichards That's very much possible, I wasn't sure which version of Nova you were using, but the concept would go on similar line. In general, a good way to understand what exception is being thrown (and from which file) is to catch the generic exception and put a `import traceback; print_traceback()` statement, which will tell the whole path of execution upto that exception to you.

Comment: @MRichards If that helped, dont forget to accept and upvote :)